# Problem using pragma omp parallel for to compute pi

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I have written the following code to compute the value of pi and it works:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static long num_steps = 1000000;
double step;
#define NUM_THREADS 16

int main()
{
    int i, nthreads;
    double tdata, pi, sum[NUM_THREADS];
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;

    tdata = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i, id, nthrds;
        double x;
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
        if (id == 0)
            nthreads = nthrds;
        for (i = id, sum[id] = 0.0; i < num_steps; i = i + nthrds)
        {
            x = (i + 0.5) * step;
            sum[id] = sum[id] + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
    }

    tdata = omp_get_wtime() - tdata;
    for (i = 0, pi = 0.0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        pi = pi + sum[i] * step;
    }
    printf("pi=%f and it took %f seconds", pi, tdata);
}
```

Then I learned that I can use `#pragma omp parallel for` and then I don't have to manually break the computation to different threads. So I wrote this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static long num_steps = 1000000;
double step;
#define NUM_THREADS 16

int main()
{
    int i;
    double tdata, pi, x, sum = 0.0;
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;

    tdata = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    {
        for (i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
        {
            x = (i + 0.5) * step;
            sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
    }

    tdata = omp_get_wtime() - tdata;
    pi = sum * step;
    printf("pi = %f and compute time = %f seconds", pi, tdata);
}
```

This, however, doesn't work and outputs wrong values of pi. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two race conditions in your code that are leading to incorrect results:

- One was already pointed out in the comments, *i.e.,*  the updates of the variable `sum` (**shared among threads**), which can be solved with the [reduction](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html) clause;
- The other is the updates of the variable `x`, which is also **shared among the threads**. This race condition can be solved by simply making that variable *private* to threads.

Two possible solutions:

1. Using the OpenMP's [private](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-data.html#Privatedata) constructor

   ```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) private(x)
    for (i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
    {
         x = (i + 0.5) * step;
         sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    }
   ```
2. Declaring the variable 'x' within the scope of the *parallel for*

   ```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
    {
         double x = (i + 0.5) * step;
         sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    }
   ```

The final code could look like the following:

```
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    static long num_steps = 1000000;
    #define NUM_THREADS 16

    int main()
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
        double step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;
    
        double tdata = omp_get_wtime();
    
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
        for (int i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
        {
             double x = (i + 0.5) * step;
             sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
    
        tdata = omp_get_wtime() - tdata;
        double pi = sum * step;
        printf("pi = %f and compute time = %f seconds", pi, tdata);
    }
```